# PowerBI: How to save result of R script?

Tags: r, powerbi, linear-programming

Is it possible to implement the following scenario in Power BI Desktop?

1. Load data from Excel file to several tables
2. Make calculation with R script from several data sources
3. Store results of calculation to new table in Power BI (.pbix)

The idea is to use Power BI Desktop for solving "transportation problem" with linear programming in R. Before solver will be running we need to make data transformations from several data sources. I'm new in Power BI. I see that it is possible to apply R scripts for loading and transformation of data, and visualizations. But I need the possibility of saving the results of calculation, for the subsequent visualization by the regular means of Power BI. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ilya Urikh, did you get the chance to look at my answer, or was it not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897796/operations-on-multiple-tables-datasets-with-edit-queries-and-r-in-power-bi/45961614#45961614) would have solved most of your challenges. That approach replaces one of the tables with a new one after the R script, but you're specifically asking to produce a *new* table, presumably leaving the input tables untouched. I've recently written a post where you can do this using [Python in the Power Query Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947441/power-bi-using-python-on-multiple-tables-in-the-query-editor). The only difference in your case would be the R script itself.

Here's how I would do it with an R script:

---

**Data samples:**

*Table1*

```
Date,Value1
2108-10-12,1
2108-10-13,2
2108-10-14,3
2108-10-15,4
2108-10-16,5
```

*Table2*

```
Date,Value2
2108-10-12,10
2108-10-13,11
2108-10-14,12
2108-10-15,13
2108-10-16,14
```

**Power Query Editor:**

With these tables loaded either from Excel or CSV files, you've got this setup in the `Power Query Editor:`:

[image]

Now you can follow these steps to get a new table using an R script:

**1.** [Change the data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929420/python-script-in-power-bi-returns-date-as-microsoft-oledb-date/51929430#51929430) of the `Date Column` to `Text`

**2.** Click `Enter Data` and click `OK` to get an empty table named `Table3` by default.

**3.** Select the `Transform` tab and click `Run R Script` to open the `Run R Script Edtor`.

**4.** Leave it empty and click `OK`.

**5.** Remove `= R.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script",[dataset=#"Changed Type"])` from the `Formula Bar` and insert this: `= R.Execute("# R Script:",[df1=Table1, df2=Table2])`.

**6.** If you're promted to do so, click `Edit Permission` and `Run`.

**7.** Click the gear symbol next to `Run R Scritp` under `APPLIED STEPS` and insert the following snippet:

**R script:**

```
df3 <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "Date", all.x = TRUE)
df3$Value3 <- df1$Value1 + df2$Value2
```

This snippet produces a new dataframe `df3` by [joining df1 and df2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right), and adds a new column `Value3`. This is a very simple setup but now you can do pretty much anything by just replacing the join and calculation methods:

[image]

**8.** Click `Home > Close&Apply` to get back to Power BI Desktop (Consider changing the data type of the `Date column` in `Table3` from `Text` to `Date` before you do that, depending on how you'd like you tables, charts and slicers to behave.)

**9.** Insert a simple table to make sure everything went smoothly

[image]

I hope this was exactly what you were looking for. Let me know if not and I'll take another look at it.