# How to display an interactive R data frame in a Power BI dashboard

Tags: r, powerbi

I would like to display an R dataframe as a table in Power BI.  Using the "R script visual" widget, here is one possible solution:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
d<-head(df[,1:3])
grid.table(d)
```

reference: [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html][1]

As stated in the reference - this approach only works for *small* tables.

Is there an alternative approach that will allow an R data frame to be displayed as a table in Power BI - specifically for larger tables that can be 'scrolled'?

Comment: I see this in the reopen queue but as an R user, I'm unable to understand what error is being considered. So it seems much less an R issue and far more a [powerbi] issue. It doesn't look reproducible and and i'm unable to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an `R Visualization`. Use the `Run R Script` functionality in the `Power Query Editor` instead (`Home > Edit Queries`).

If you follow the steps in posts [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120853/how-to-save-result-of-r-script-in-power-bi/51965134#51965134) and/or [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897796/operations-on-multiple-tables-datasets-with-edit-queries-and-r-in-power-bi/45961614#45961614) you'll see how you can import and transform any data into any table you want using R.

So with a simple dataset such as:

```
A,B
1,11
2,19
3,18
4,19
5,18
6,12
7,12
8,19
9,13
10,19
```

... you can produce a scrollable table of any format in Power BI:

**R script:**

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
dataset$C <- dataset$B*2
dataset2 <- dataset
```

**Power Query Editor:**
[image]

**Power BI Desktop table:**

[image]

**Power BI Desktop interactive table:**

And you can easily make the table interactive by introducing a `slicer`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you now also have the possibility of importing an R DataTable visualization from the Power BI Marketplace:

[image]

With the same dataset, you'll end up with this:

[image]

Comment: Is it still available? Can't find any official documentation anymore, just the 2 year old git repos.