# From R script to Power Bi - how to use setdiff

Tags: r, powerbi, set-difference

I've got two data frames: `zerowy_nazwa5`, `zatwierdzony_nazwa5`,

and working 2 lines:

```
setdiff(zatwierdzony_nazwa5, zerowy_nazwa5)
setdiff(zerowy_nazwa5, zatwierdzony_nazwa5)
```

how I implement this in PowerBi?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you expand your question? Do you have an R session and do you want to create a table in PowerBI with the data? Do you want to do something simulate setdiff on PowerBI without using R? ...

Comment: I want to transform my R script to PowerBi. Data import from R gives me two tables in PowerBi. I want to run setdiff on PowerBI on this two tables with using R function setdiff.

Comment: From PowerBI you can not execute functions of R, you can use R to generate graphics and within the script you can do any operation, but you can not return the operations as tables. You have an option that is to run `setdiff` in the R script that generates your data.frame's and enter PowerBI 3 objects instead of two (where the third one is a data.frame with the two `sediff).

Comment: Ok. I do this in R. A <-setdiff(zatwierdzony_nazwa5, zerowy_nazwa5)but I wonder if it possible to this more dynamic using Power Bi

Comment: I was thinking about making function in R and arguments of this function in PowerBi - but You write that is no possibile.

Comment: It is only possible if the output is a plot of R, if you want to return data it is not possible. [See this.](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/r-visuals-in-powerbi-service/)

Comment: Juan is correct. You cannot use R within a DAX measure. However, you can certainly compute a set difference using just DAX or M, so there's no need for R in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question, I'm assuming this:

1. Your main goal is to do this internally in PowerBI
2. You're not specifically asking how to do it using DAX

The Power of R in Power BI is *not* limited to R Visuals. You can load both [single](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-r-in-query-editor) and multiple tables and use them as input to R scripts and *any* R functionality using `Edit Queries > Transform > Run R Script`.

Here's an example using two synthetic dataframes and setdiff():

**Snippet 1** (from the dplyr::setdiff examples in R)

```
library(dplyr)
a <- data.frame(column = c(1:10, 10))
b <- data.frame(column = c(1:5, 5))
c <- dplyr::setdiff(a, b)

# Output
# column
# 1      6
# 2      7
# 3      8
# 4      9
# 5     10
```

Since you didn't describe your expected output, I'm assuming this is what you were after. But beware that if you're not using the `dplyr` library, base::setdiff() will give a different output:

**Snippet 2**

```
c <- base::setdiff(a, b)

# output

# column
# 1       1
# 2       2
# 3       3
# 4       4
# 5       5
# 6       6
# 7       7
# 8       8
# 9       9
# 10     10
```

And if you carefully follow the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120853/how-to-save-result-of-r-script-in-power-bi/51965134#51965134) you *will* be a able to end up with this in Power BI. But here's the essence of it: To reproduce the example, go to `Edit Queries (Power Query Editor) > Enter Data` and click `OK`. Then insert an R script using `Transform > Run R script` and insert the snippet above.

[image]

If anything is unclear, or if you're not able to reproduce the result, let me know.

Comment: Also works in text data:
library(dplyr) 
a_text <- data.frame(column = c("A","B","C","D","E")) 

b_text <- data.frame(column = c("B","C","G")) 
c_text <- dplyr::setdiff(a_text, b_text) 
d_text <- dplyr::setdiff(b_text, a_text) ... sorry for formating

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather unclear, so I'm going to have to make some assumptions.
I will interpret your question as how to natively perform a set difference in Power BI.

---

Suppose we have tables `A` and `B` as follows

```
Table A:   Table B:      
Column     Column
------     ------
 1          2
 2          4
 3
 4
 5
```

and we want to get the set difference `A - B`

```
 Column
 ------
  1
  3
  5
```

You can do it in DAX or in the Power Query M language:

---

**M language**

You can do this using a **left anti join**. The M code looks like this:

```
 = Table.NestedJoin(A,{"Column"},B,{"Column"},"B",JoinKind.LeftAnti)
```

Delete the new "B" column and you're good to go.

Another way is to use the `Table.SelectRows` function:

```
= Table.SelectRows(A, each not List.Contains(B[Column], _[Column]))
```

---

**DAX language**

You just need to filter table `A` to exclude values in table `B`:

```
FILTER(A, NOT( A[Column] IN VALUES( B[Column] ) ) )
```

Or using the older `CONTAINS` syntax instead of `IN`:

```
FILTER(A, NOT( CONTAINS( VALUES( B[Column] ), B[Column], A[Column] ) ) )
```

---

Note: It certainly is possible to use R scripts within the Power Query environment, as vestland points out. It is not currently possible to use R scripts within a DAX expression, as Juan points out.

Comment: very usefull for any number data, thank You @alexisolson